# angular 7 navigation issue- routerLink not redirecting to another page

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, navigation

This is how my first component list data from node web api. When I click on the subject it does't redirect to the next page.

//List all unique subjects

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let subject of subjects">
     <a [routerLink]="['/student/',subject.subjectId]" >{{subject.subject}}</a>
      </li>
  </ul>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
//fetch unique subjects using node api
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'List unique Subjects';
  subjects: any = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/Subject').subscribe(data =>{


      console.log(data);
      this.subjects = data;
    })
  }
}
```

Here is my second component . It shows an error in the console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘innerHTML’ of undefined

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  template: `<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let student of students">
      {{student.studentId}}
      </li>
  </ul>`,

  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css']
})

//fetch student details according to the passing subject id
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Student list';
    students: any = [];

 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
  ngOnInit(//alert(this.activeAouter.snapshot.params['id'])
  ){
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:5000/api/Student/ACC3TAX').subscribe(data =>{


      console.log(data);
      this.students = data;
    })
  }
}
```

and my routing module

```
  const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', component: AppComponent },

{ path: '/student/:id',component: studentComponent },

    ];
```

Comment: In AppComponent : 

<a [routerLink]="['/student/',subject.subjectId]" >{{subject.subject}}</a>
 ---->
'student' is in small case.

in Routes : 

{ path: 'api/Student/:id',redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }  ---->

'Student' is in camel-case. It might be due to case mis-match.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues.

1. If you were to use `[routerLink]="['/student...` in the component, then `path: 'api/Student/:id'` should actually be `path: 'student/:id'`.

Routing module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: StudentComponent },
  { path: 'student/:id',redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

2. Remove the forward slash at the end of `'/student/`. Replace `[routerLink]="['/student/',subject.subjectId]"` with `[routerLink]="['/student',subject.subjectId]"`.

Component template

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/student', subject?.subjectId]" >{{subject.subject}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

In your routing.module.ts,

Edit the path, to `api/student/:id`

In your app.component.ts,

Remove the extra `/` in the `/student/`

```
template: <ul>
               <li *ngFor="let subject of subjects">
                 <a [routerLink]="['api/student', subject.subjectId]" >{{subject.subject}}</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
```

Also, in your student.component.ts file,
You are using `templateUrl` with `template`. You should use either one of them depending upon the complexity of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You have something to fix in your code:

1) You don't need to declare api endpoint in angular routes, but your application routes, so in your router the path `api/Student/:id` should be `Student/:id` (you can even have api prefix if you want but here it looked like a mistake :)). 
After this you should remove the leading / before student from `[routerLink]="['/Student/',subject.subjectId]"`

2) You are using `templateUrl` and `template` in the same decorator, they needs to be unique so you have to choose between them.

I also suggest you to enable router tracing in your application while debugging, so you can have more information about routing errors. You can enable it this way:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
]
```